# Detect when user writes/deletes file in specific folder

Tags: c#, .net

I have inherited application that, among many other things, has to watch if user writes/deletes text file into specific folder.

Currently, the application uses timer and polls after 5 seconds. I find this ineffective, and wish to improve this part of code.

My question is about existence of the .NET function that monitors changes in directory. Is there such function I can use to detect when a file is written/deleted in a specified folder?

Thank you.

Comment: Have a look at [`FileSystemWatcher`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you have the [`FileSystemWatcher`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class. It does exactly what you're looking for

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is.  I would suggest you take a look at the FileSystemWatcher class:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

It's quite easy to set up, and it monitors for Win32 events, so is relatively inexpensive to use.